# Correlation matrix in panel data in R

Tags: r, dplyr, panel-data

I have a time-series panel dataset which is structured in the following way:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  year = c(2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L),
  id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
  c = c(11L, 13L, 13L, 16L, 15L, 15L)
)

#>   year id  c
#> 1 2012  1 11
#> 2 2013  1 13
#> 3 2014  1 13
#> 4 2012  2 16
#> 5 2013  2 15
#> 6 2014  2 15
```

I would like to find the cross-correlation between values in column C given their id number. 
Something similar to this:

```r
#>     1  2
#> 1   1  0.8
#> 2   0.8  1
```

I have been using dplyr package to find the cross-correlation between two variables in my panel data but for some reason, I can't do the same for cross correlation in one veriable grouped by id.

Comment: If you can include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) it'll be easier for people to help.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to do this, but you might want to check out [`widyr`](https://github.com/dgrtwo/widyr)

Comment: `cor(unstack(df[ , -1], c ~ id))`

Comment: When I try to implement the Henrik solution: I get an error which asks me to supply both 'x' and 'y' or a matrix-like 'x'. It might be helpful to note that in my actual problem I have around 12 different id numbers instead of 2 in this example.

Answer (score 2):

If you are already using `tidyverse` tools, you should try [`widyr`](https://github.com/dgrtwo/widyr).

Its functions reshape to wide, get the correlations, and give you back a tidy data frame again.

(Note I changed the sample data slightly to match [akaDrHouse's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4001897/akadrhouse) answer.

```r
df <- data.frame(
  year = c(2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L),
  id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
  c = c(11L, 13L, 13L, 16L, 15L, 156L)
)

df
#>   year id   c
#> 1 2012  1  11
#> 2 2013  1  13
#> 3 2014  1  13
#> 4 2012  2  16
#> 5 2013  2  15
#> 6 2014  2 156

widyr::pairwise_cor(df, id, year, c)

#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   item1 item2 correlation
#>   <int> <int>       <dbl>
#> 1     2     1   0.4946525
#> 2     1     2   0.4946525

widyr::pairwise_cor(df, id, year, c, upper = FALSE)

#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   item1 item2 correlation
#>   <int> <int>       <dbl>
#> 1     1     2   0.4946525
```

Comment: Nice functionality @austensen. I've not heard of widyr.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like the following?  I used the reshape package to cast based on the value of your id, followed by the `cor()` function in baseR.

```
> mydf <- data.frame(year=c("12","13","14","12","13","14"),id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2),c=c(11,13,13,16,15,156))
> library(reshape2)
> mydf
  year id   c
1   12  1  11
2   13  1  13
3   14  1  13
4   12  2  16
5   13  2  15
6   14  2 156
> my_wide_data <- dcast(mydf, year~id,value.var="c")
> cor(my_wide_data[,2:3])
          1         2
1 1.0000000 0.4946525
2 0.4946525 1.0000000
```

So @Henrik's comment was much more simple and elegant, so including here.

```
> cor(unstack(mydf[ , -1], c ~ id))
          X1        X2
X1 1.0000000 0.4946525
X2 0.4946525 1.0000000
```