# Calculate correlation matrx for panel data in R

Tags: r, correlation, panel-data

I have panel data set of firms:

```
df <- structure(list(id = c("00127264", "00127264", "00127264", "00127264", 
"00127264", "00127264", "00127264", "00127264", "00127264", "00127264", 
"00127264", "00127264", "00127264", "00127264", "00127264", "00128538", 
"00128538", "00128538", "00128538", "00128538", "00128538", "00128538", 
"00128538", "00128538", "00128538", "00129879", "00129879", "00129879", 
"00129879", "00129879", "00129879", "00129879", "00129879", "00129879", 
"00129879", "00132241", "00132241", "00132241", "00132241", "00132241", 
"00132241", "00132241", "00132241", "00132241", "00132241", "00132241", 
"00132241", "00132241", "00132241", "00132241"), time = c(2003L, 
2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 
2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 
2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2003L, 2004L, 
2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 
2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L), sales = c(18778913, 26246705, 24577605, 
20555975, 22803119, 30493587, 47409381, 39648917, 24164698, 26667934, 
36939340, 37303488, 36095594, 47863204, 81470728, 17082948, 19218374, 
17775729, 18719393, 17682127, 17648132, 19868021, 20034845, 20291386, 
28511274, 23842198, 33364335, 38006554, 44051316, 41017519, 44559215, 
38096697, 39532944, 32250063, 20456725, 36737613, 36788480, 34432314, 
45703706, 51318203, 57966879, 57314960, 69108257, 83337772, 95862115, 
78796350, 73897366, 122529286, 114051176, 140727472), costs = c(2776879, 
6661626, 7383728, 8148280, 6965171, 15952938, 28537059, 20336344, 
8049578, 8313115, 17175621, 17864169, 17323966, 25772512, 56918048, 
13617240, 14974971, 13919060, 14317811, 13879155, 14374214, 14607183, 
14718348, 15511957, 22142396, 21523985, 30354647, 33001065, 38699618, 
35369730, 50308253, 37174212, 38743973, 28852158, 16476830, 31420842, 
30050214, 28193685, 35918673, 40847638, 45944119, 44448831, 56898404, 
70216220, 80454840, 63808983, 60155914, 106046623, 96525104, 
119211752)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

As you can see, it has 4 columns: id, time, sales and costs.
I would like to calculate correlations between sales and costs for all firms. For example, I would like to calculate correlations between sales of firm with ID 00127264 with costs of all other firms ("00128538" "00129879" "00132241"). Correlation should take into account the time dimension. The panel data set is unbalanced.

I have found similar problem and solution here:
 [Correlation matrix in panel data in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44348269/correlation-matrix-in-panel-data-in-r)
but `widyr` package can calculate correlations for one value variable only:

```
widyr::pairwise_cor(sample, id, year, sales)
```

and I would need something like

```
widyr::pairwise_cor(sample, id, year, c(sales, costs))
```

which is not possible.
Expected output (correlations are just some random numbers):

from    to      corr

127264  128538  0,54

127264  129879  0,68

127264  132241  0,78

128538  127264  0,43

128538  129879  0,48

128538  132241  0,17

129879  127264  0,57

129879  128538  0,36

129879  132241  0,89

132241  127264  0,15

132241  128538  0,6

132241  129879  0,8

or it can be a correlation matrix, as I mentioned.